# click button on url change (with scrolling)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am a novice in web coding and I had a problem with the implementation of this simple code.

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function(e, direction){
    if (direction === 'up') {
        $(".prev").click();
    }   
    else {
        $(".next").click();
    }
});
```

So, when user `scrolling down` and url is changing - click button `.next` (this part is work fine). When `scrolling at top`&url changing -> click `.prev` (It does not work).

And i have another one question. Will this code work fine without hashtag in URL? (`mysite.com/?p=1` for example).

So html part is just:

```
<div id="p1" class="width:100%; height:500px;"></div>
<div id="p2" class="width:100%; height:500px;"></div>
<div class="next"></div>
<div class="prev"></div>
```

And there is another one js code, which change url when user scroll top/down of this div's.
Don't know how to detect scrolling from bottom to top...
Thanks for ur time!

Comment: Where is direction coming from? Are you sure its ever up?

Comment: You would need to post the HTML code containing (atleast) the elements used with that JS

Comment: upd. i can go another way, if u can show. I have url, that changes from #?=1 to #?=2... So when url changes from current +1 = click next, if -1 click prev... But i think this is bad idea, is not it?